# Find Expectation and Variance of S and T and compare them.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let, X~Bin(n,p) and Y~Poisson($\lambda$ ). Let
$$T=X_1+X_2+...+X_Y$$ with $X_i$'s i. i. d.  Bin(n,p) (and independent to Y) and
$$S=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_X$$ with $Y_i$'s i. i. d.  Poisson($\lambda$) (and independent to X). Compare expectation of T and S and Variance of T and S.

My attempt :

$X_i$'s i. i. d.  Bin(n,p) then $E(X_i) =np \  and \  Var(X_i) =npq$

$Y_i$'s i. i. d.  Poisson($\lambda$)  then $E(Y_i) =\lambda=Var(Y_i) $

Then $E(T) =Ynp$ and $Var(T) =Ynpq$
Also $E(S) =X\lambda$ and $Var(T) =X\lambda$
Then I can't get any relation between them.
Can anyone give me a suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

To compare the expectation and variance of T and S, let's first find their respective formulas.

1. Expectation:

Recall that the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations, and the expectation of a random variable multiplied by a constant is the constant times the expectation of the random variable.

For T:
$$
E(T) = E(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_Y) = E(Y) \cdot E(X)
$$
Since $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, p)$, $E(X) = np$.
And since $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $E(Y) = \lambda$.
So,
$$
E(T) = \lambda(np) = \lambda np
$$

For S:
$$
E(S) = E(Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_X) = E(X) \cdot E(Y)
$$
Since $E(X) = np$ and $E(Y) = \lambda$, we have:
$$
E(S) = np \cdot \lambda = \lambda np
$$

Thus, $E(T) = E(S) = \lambda np$.

2. Variance:

For T, we use the formula for the variance of the sum of independent random variables:

$$
Var(T) = E(Y) \cdot Var(X) + Var(Y) \cdot (E(X))^2
$$

Since $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, p)$, $Var(X) = np(1-p)$.
And since $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $Var(Y) = \lambda$.
So,
$$
Var(T) = \lambda(np(1-p)) + \lambda(np)^2 = \lambda np(1-p) + \lambda n^2p^2
$$

For S, we use the same formula:

$$
Var(S) = E(X) \cdot Var(Y) + Var(X) \cdot (E(Y))^2
$$

Since $Var(X) = np(1-p)$ and $Var(Y) = \lambda$, we have:
$$
Var(S) = np(\lambda) + np(1-p)(\lambda)^2 = \lambda np + \lambda^2 np(1-p)
$$

In conclusion, we have:

- $E(T) = E(S) = \lambda np$
- $Var(T) = \lambda np(1-p) + \lambda n^2p^2$
- $Var(S) = \lambda np + \lambda^2 np(1-p)$

Comment: Why E(X_1)+E(X_2)+...E(X_Y)= E(Y) E(X)  ? Why not YE(X)?